# Carbon::now returns wrong month

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I'm trying to make cron job for my system.
The project is configured for time zone that differs from mine
I tried

```
$timezone = date_default_timezone_get();
$current = Carbon::now(new \DateTimeZone($timezone));
```

It returns `2018-01-05 06:36:15`
which had a wrong month
I tried `$current_m = date('y-m-d h:m');` which returned

```
18-02-06 06:02
```

which had right date but wrong time
what should I do? I need to be using carbon $ I'm using laravel 5.4

Answer (score -2):

The problem wasn't in Carbon, It was in using `$current->subHours(48)` several times.